# How to delete a item in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

Hi I need to delete an Item in a XML file, I can add to it no problem but would like to know how to adjust one Item in the file.  I need to delete the Item with the name Mike in it and the date, how do I achieve this?

Edit: I'm getting a `NullReferenceException`

here is my XML

```
<Items>
 <Item>
  <Name>Mike</Name>
  <Date>5/4/2000</Date>
 </Item>
 <Item>
  <Name>Martin</Name>
  <Date>5/4/2010</Date>
 </Item>
</Items>
```

This is the code I am trying

```
public void deleteElement()
    {
        //Get users private store info
        IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream;

        //open selected file
        isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Item.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, isoStore);
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
        isoStream.Close();

        //Find section
        XElement sectionElement = xml.Descendants("Item").Where(c => c.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Mike")).FirstOrDefault();

        //Find item and remove it
        sectionElement.Elements("Item").Where(c => c.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Mike")).FirstOrDefault().Remove();
        isoStream.Close();  //Seems unnecessary but it's needed.

        //Write xml file
        isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Item.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, isoStore);
        xml.Save(isoStream);
        isoStream.Close();


    }
```

I would appreciate if you could help me thanks.

Comment: At which line does the `NullReferenceException` happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml.Root.Elements("Item")
        .Where(item => item.Element("Name").Value == "Mike")
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .Remove();
```

Produces:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Name>Martin</Name>
    <Date>5/4/2010</Date>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Note a few things:

- Started searching for direct elements under the root element ("Items") called "Item", but not their children.
- Under the item element, look for the "Name" *element* (not attribute) with the relevant value ("Mike")

Comment: It's giving me an error at this line `var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);` saving `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' to 'string'
`  What should the parameter xml be as I am getting a stream from isolated storage?

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with your variable names. I had `xml` as a string and `doc` as my `XDocument`. You have `xml` as your `XDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this Xml Library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) you can write it like:

```
XElement mike = xml.Root.XPathElement("Item[Name='Mike']");
mike.Remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance it seems as if you are trying to retrieve the same element twice.

```
// Retrieve the desired Item element
XElement sectionElement = xml.Descendants("Item").Where(c => c.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Mike")).FirstOrDefault();
// Retrieve (and remove) the desired Item element
// This line will fail, as there is no Item descendants of the Item element
sectionElement.Elements("Item").Where(c => c.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Mike")).FirstOrDefault().Remove();
```

How about just using one line?

```
xml.Descendants("Item").Where(c => c.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Mike")).FirstOrDefault().Remove();
```

BTW: I do not recognize the methods used, but "Name" is probably not an attribute, but rather an element.

Comment: Appreciated what you tried to do here, but the answer is not right.